# Active Admin with devise multiple user roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

I was wondering how can I create a smooth flow of user roles with Active Admin and devise.

I need to create 3 roles: user, moderator, administrator

I saw this post here:
https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-to-Setup-Multiple-Devise-User-Models

Right now that post says that there are only 2 roles.

Is there any other smooth way to attain this with Active Admin, Devise and Ruby on Rails 6?

What are the steps to take? Please help a newbie!

Answer (score 0):

use rolify gem. It will provide you more than 2 role options and also you can create a roles table with has_and_belongs_to_many :users option but i will suggest you to use gem.